# RegEx to extract Contact Name and email from string

Tags: regex, string, asp-classic

I'm trying to come up with some RegEx to extract name and email address from a string.

I know there are tons of questions about this here, and just went through some and they don't work for me.

This is the RegEx I have so far

```
([\'(\w\d\s*)\'\s]*)<([a-z\d._%+-]+@[a-z\d.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\b)>
```

The strings can be like

```
Name Surname email@domain.com

'Name Surname' <email@domain.com>

'Name Surname' email@domain.com

Name Surname <email@domain.com>
```

So I guess you could see that both the ' and the < > can be entirely optional.

I need it to get the results in two groups, one for the contact name and one for the email.

I'm using classic asp due to legacy code in the company.

Thanks

Comment: Try [`'?(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)'?\s+<?(\S+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/jV4vO1/1)

Comment: Are you saying that given the strings above you want to use regex to extract two pieces of data, the name and the email?

Comment: @RudyTheHunter That is correct, I'd like to groups one with the Name Surname bit and one with the email address

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That worked! Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad to help, posted with explanations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
'?(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)'?\s+<?(\S+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jV4vO1/1)

**Pattern explanation**:

- `'?` - an optional `'`
- `(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)` - Group 1 matching:

  - `\w+` - 1 or more alphanumeric/underscore symbols
  - `(?:\s+\w+)*` - 0 or more sequences of 1+ whitespaces followed with 1+ alphanumeric/underscore symbols
- `'?` - an optional `'`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace symbols
- `<?`  - an optional `<`
- `(\S+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b)` - Group 2 matching

  - `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace symbols
  - `@` - a literal `@`
  - `[\w.-]+` - 1 or more characters: alphanumeric/underscore, dot or hyphen
  - `\.` - a literal dot
  - `[a-zA-Z]{2,4}` - 2 to 4 ASCII letters
  - `\b` - a trailing word boundary

Comment: That's great thanks, now how would you update it so the Name part is optional? For example if I get just email@domain.com in the string ?

Comment: Use [`'?(\w+(?:\s+\w+)*)?'?\s*<?(\S+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/jV4vO1/2).

Answer (score 0):

Here are two Regex.  Use the first to get the email out of the string and the second to get a two part name.

```
Email
[\w\.\-]+@(([\w\-]+)\.)+(\w){2,3}

Name
\b[a-zA-Z]*[^\s@.]\b\s?\b[a-zA-Z]*[^\s@.]\b
```